# Make excel count sequentially in between text

Tags: excel

I want to make a column in my excel spreadsheet that looks kind of like this:

```
AA____001_XLA
AA____002_XLA
AA____003_XLA
AA____004_XLAN
AA____005_XLAN
AA____006_XLAN
AA____007_TLA
AA____008_TLA
AA____009_TLA
AA____010_TLAN
...
```

Basically, it's a three-digit number counting upwards in between two text / symbol - fragments. But seeing as the list is gonna be rather long, I'm looking for a way to extend the list automatically. I'm just looking for a way to make the numbers in the middle count upwards, the text around it I'll adjust manually.

Comment: Welcome to SO. While Excel equations are posted on StackOverflow, you might get a better response on SuperUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in A1, you can do 
`="AA_____"&TEXT(ROW(),"000")&"_XLAN"`, and drag down.

If you're starting in a row other than 1, then use `Text(Row()-x,"000")` where `x` is the `Starting Row - 1` (i.e. if your formula starts in A100, use `Text(Row()-99,"000")`

Comment: +1, but It might make sense to have The "AA" part in column A, the "XLAN" part in Column B and something that concatenates them together with `TEXT(ROW())` in Column C since OP mentioned needing to be able to adjust the text parts separately.

Comment: @JohnColeman - Excellent point. I just left it like so, since OP said he'd adjust manually.  However, OP - if there's some pattern/way to know what the end text will be, we can probably work that in to this as well.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. No pattern for the surrounding bits of text unfortunately, but it's fairly static, so search & replace will take care of it quickly enough.